# Is Bash part of Apple's OS X System Update?

Tags: macos, bash

I think the title is self explanatory.  How safe is it to upgrade yourself using methods such as this (https://coderwall.com/p/dmuxma)?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably get a answer on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's two questions.

As of now there hasn't been an Apple update including replacement shells.

Simply changing the log in shell to a built one isn't sufficient. It doesn't include sh and shell scripts can refer to the 'proper shells', (e.g. #!/bin/sh).

See [How do I recompile Bash to avoid the remote exploit CVE-2014-6271?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271)  on Ask Different for something a bit more comprehensive than your link.

Notice we were nit picking over security.  The directions if followed explicitly don't do anything that can't be undone.

Comment: Ah thank you. Not a lot of threads about this subject pop on my radar yesterday, but yes, it's exploit related. Thanks again.